# PHP gzinflate() in C?

Tags: php, c, zlib

I'm trying since several hours to implement the behaviour of PHP gzinflate() in C. In PHP it's just:
gzinflate($str);
In Python it's: 
import zlib
...
return zlib.decompress( decoded_data , -15)
...
But I just don't manage to implement it in C. Can anybody help me with that? I'm really stuck.. I tried to do something with Zlib but it didn't work.. Anybody got a point?

Thanks in advance,

nemo

Answer (score 5):

This [zlib usage example](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html) is very thorough.

Note that you are closer to the bare metal here than in Python or PHP, so the usage isn't as simple.

**Addendum:**

The PHP `gzinflate` and `gzdeflate` functions perform input and output raw DEFLATE format.  The zlib functions, on the other hand, work by default with zlib streams, which are the same with the addition of a 2 byte header and a 4 byte trailer.

You can either switch to using the PHP `gzcompress` and `gzuncompress` functions, which produce ZLIB format, or (if you have a recent version of zlib) use the `deflateInit2` function instead of `deflateInit` and specify a negative value for `windowBits`, which requests raw DEFLATE format.

Comment: Yes, I took a look at that but I'm just not able to create something that works. I can compress and uncompress things, but I don't manage to uncompress a string which was deflated with gzdeflate.